# Multiple google charts in a page break on rendering

Tags: javascript, html, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/), and I'm trying to insert two bar charts in a single HTML page.

Graphs data is loaded from two separate AJAX requests, and it is correctly rendered as you can see below:

[image]

When I update first graph's data by running again the first AJAX request, it breaks visualization for the second graph:

[image]

This happens only for vertically aligned graphs. At a first look, it seems like the visualization breaks relatively to the span of data of the first graph. I'm also using bootstrap 3. I include relevant code:

Markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="chart">
      <div class="chart-content" id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="chart">
      <div class="chart-content" id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}

.chart-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var charts = {}

var chart1Update = function() {
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(res){
      // res manipulation
      // ...
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(res);

      var options = {
        legend: {position: 'none'},
        bars: 'horizontal',
        bar: {groupWidth: "90%"},
        colors: ['#26A9D4']
      }

      if(!charts.chart1){
        charts.chart1 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart1'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(charts.chart1, 'ready', function(){ // .. irrelevant stuff }

        charts.chart1.draw(data, options);
    }
  })
}

// chart2Update -> identical to chart1Update with only reference to chart1 changed to chart2, plus a different color
```

Any idea on how to solve this or at least how to investigate on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, it's a bug confirmed by Google Visualization API developers. https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1916